# Feign get request with body

Tags: spring-boot, feign, openfeign

For some reason I need to call a GET method API and pass json request body for it. I really couldn't find an example for it. I wonder if it is even supported using feign. 
How can I do that using feign?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, Feign supports it. You can do the same as with POST requests:

```
@FeignClient(name = "clientName", url = "http://localhost:8888")
public interface SampleFeignClient {

    @GetMapping("/remote")
    String test(@RequestBody SampleRequestBody sampleRequestBody);
}
```

But be aware: a lot of servers ignore body or even refuse that kind of "non-standard" requests completely (GET or HEAD with request bodies).

Comment: This approach works if, additionally, you use the Apache HTTP client as stated in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76434131/3772679

Answer (score 6):

According to the documentation the correct way to do it would be to use the `@SpringQueryMap` annotation.

```
@FeignClient(name = "clientName", url = "http://localhost:8888")
public interface SampleFeignClient {

    @GetMapping("/remote")
    String test(@SpringQueryMap SampleRequestBody sampleRequestBody);
}
```

You can find more information [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-openfeign/reference/html/#feign-querymap-support)