# Send a query in a GET Http method

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, openfeign

I am trying to communicate with an external web service (Elastic search API) using java, but without using any elasticsearch library, so I created a query class that match the request that we gonna send to elsaticsearch API :

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query":    "this is a test", 
      "fields": [ "subject", "message" ] 
    }
  }
}
```

here is the equivalant class :

```
@Data
class QueryRequest{
   private Query query;
}

@Data
class Query{
   private Match multi_match;
}

@Data
class Match{
   private String query;
   private Lis<String> fields;
}
```

to fetch this API using curl we need to write this request :

```
curl --location --request GET <host> --header 'Content-Type : application/json' --data-row '{  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query":    "this is a test", 
      "fields": [ "subject", "message" ] 
    }
  }}'
```

my question is how I can send this kind of request using feign client

Comment: Actually, to serach in elastic search API you can use GET or POST, so in this case it's possible to switch for a ```@PostMapping``` with a ```@RequestBody``` : 
```
@FeignClient(url=<host>, name=<client name>)
interface ESClient{
   @PostMapping("/_search")
   Data searchData(@RequestBody RequestQuery query);
}
```



NB : it's better to enable debbug mode, check this link to enable it : https://www.baeldung.com/java-feign-logging

Comment: possible duplicate of this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61083055/feign-get-request-with-body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61083055/feign-get-request-with-body)

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking form is "QUERY" HTTP Method, but I'm not sure if it's fully implemented. Here is some aditional information:

[IETF](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-httpbis-safe-method-w-body/)

https://horovits.medium.com/http-s-new-method-for-data-apis-http-query-1ff71e6f73f3

Comment: This is only a draft specification, it is unfortunately not supported by anyone at the moment.